# VS2010 с++/cli считывание и создание xml файла

Tags: xml, c++-cli

с++/cli vs2010. При открытии окна происходит загрузка в combobox xml файла (размер файла около 3мб), на данном этапе происходит подвисание программы.
При полной загрузке файла программа начинает работать корректно. Далее происходит выборка необходимых Point с последующей записью их (с имеющимися атрибутами) в xml файл и в итоге на выходе имеем:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <point>
    <pr_name></pr_name>
    <atribut1></atribut1>
    <atribut2></atribut2>
  </point>
  <point>
    <pr_name></pr_name>
    <atribut1></atribut1>
    <atribut2></atribut2>
  </point>
  <point>
    <pr_name></pr_name>
    <atribut1></atribut1>
    <atribut2></atribut2>
  </point>
</NewDataSet>
```

Как сделать, чтоб результат работы был таким:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<NewDataSet>
  <point>
    <pr_name></pr_name>
    <atribut1></atribut1>
    <atribut2></atribut2>
  </point>
  <point>
    <pr_name></pr_name>
    <atribut1></atribut1>
    <atribut2></atribut2>
  </point>
  <point>
    <pr_name></pr_name>
    <atribut1></atribut1>
    <atribut2></atribut2>
  </point>
</NewDataSet>
```

Как ускорить процесс загрузки xml файла или сделать его незаметным для пользователя? Как правильно добавлять и удалять узлы из xml файла?

```
XmlPoint = L"Data/labelName.xml";
if(File::Exists(XmlPoint)) 
    {
        docPoint = gcnew XmlDocument();
        docPoint->Load(XmlPoint);   
        for each(XmlNode ^i in docPoint->DocumentElement->ChildNodes) 
        {
            comboBoxPoint->Items->Add( i["pr_name"]->InnerText );
        } 
    }       
    else 
    {
        MessageBox::Show(L"The file " + XmlPoint + L" was not found");
    }

System::Void Form3::PointSaveDoc(XmlDocument ^docWay, String ^Pr_name, String ^PointAtribut1, String ^PointAtribut2)
{
    XmlNode ^elemWaypoint = docWay->CreateElement("point");

    XmlElement ^elemPr_name = docWay->CreateElement( "pr_name" );
    elemPr_name->InnerText = Pr_name;

    XmlElement ^elemAtribut1 = docWay->CreateElement( "atribut1" );
    elemAtribut1->InnerText = PointAtribut1;

    XmlElement ^elemAtribut2= docWay->CreateElement( "atribut2" );
    elemLongitude->InnerText = PointAtribut2;

    docWay->DocumentElement->AppendChild(elemWaypoint);
    elemWaypoint->AppendChild(elemPr_name);
    elemWaypoint->AppendChild(elemAtribut1);
    elemWaypoint->AppendChild(elemAtribut2);
}

//Выбранные точки по имени собираем в ListBox, с которого в последствии считываем по имени определяем их атрибуты из имеющегося xml файла и записываем в новый файл:

XmlDocument ^XMLNewPoint = gcnew XmlDocument;
XMLNewPoint->LoadXml( "<NewDataSet></NewDataSet>");
XmlNode ^rootNewPoint = XMLNewPoint->DocumentElement;   

String ^FileName = Name + L".xml";

for (int j = 0; j < listBoxViewSelectPoint->Items->Count; j++)
    {
        String ^ElementListBox = listBoxViewSelectPoint->Items[j]->ToString();
        for each(XmlNode ^i in docPoint->DocumentElement->ChildNodes)
        {
            if (ElementListBox == i["pr_name"]->InnerText)
            {
                PointAtribut1 = i["atribut1"]->InnerText;
                PointAtribut2 = i["atribut2"]->InnerText;
                PointSaveDoc(XMLNewPoint, ElementListBox, PointAtribut1, PointAtribut2);
            }
        }   
    }       
String ^FilePath = "Data/tmp.xml";
```

Comment: Как насчёт перехода на язык C#? Код на нём намного лаконичнее и проще, чем на C++-CLI, при этом производительность такая же. И документация лучше, больше литературы, многочисленнее сообщество. Я (или многие другие форумчане) помогли бы написать на нём код асинхронной загрузки файла xml. А на c++-cli мне жутко не хочется это делать: слишком муторно. И, как видите, людей, хорошо знающих этот язык, практически нет, помочь некому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подвисание программы происходит из-за того, что длительные действия (загрузка и парсинг файла) выполняются в GUI-потоке.

Самым простым, но нерекомендуемым, способом является применение метода [Application.DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx). Достаточно вставить его вызов в цикл:

```cpp
for each(XmlNode ^i in docPoint->DocumentElement->ChildNodes) 
{
    comboBoxPoint->Items->Add( i["pr_name"]->InnerText );
    Application::DoEvents();
}
```

Это позволит форме прорисовываться.

Кстати, желательно предотвратить повторную загрузку файла, пока не она не завершилась. Например, сделав кнопку недоступной, а после загрузки можно её включить:

```cpp
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    button1->Enabled = false;
    // здесь ваш код с DoEvents
    // при использовании потока подход будет иной
    button1->Enabled = true;
}
```

И дайте всем контролам говорящие названия! Эта кнопка, по идее, должна называться `buttonLoad`.

Более правильным способом будет перенос длительной работы в отдельный поток (`Thread`) или задачу (`Task`). При этом для доступа к компонентам формы обязательно нужно использовать [`InvokeRequired + Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

---

Добавить декларацию к XML можно разными способами. Самый простой:

```cpp
XMLNewPoint->LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\" ?><NewDataSet></NewDataSet>");
```

Более правильный - создаём узел декларации и вставляем перед корневым элементом:

```cpp
XmlDeclaration ^declaration = XMLNewPoint->CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", nullptr, "yes");
XMLNewPoint->InsertBefore(declaration, rootNewPoint);
```

Самый правильный - создаём по очереди декларацию и корневой узел, добавляем их к xml-документу:

```cpp
XmlDeclaration ^declaration = XMLNewPoint->CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", nullptr, "yes");
XMLNewPoint->AppendChild(declaration);

XmlNode ^rootNewPoint = XMLNewPoint->CreateElement("NewDataSet");
XMLNewPoint->AppendChild(rootNewPoint);
```

---

---

Для работы с XML в .NET вместо устаревшего `XmlDocument` рекомендуется использовать классы из пространства имён [System.Xml.Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq(v=vs.110).aspx).

Сперва нужно в свойствах проекта подключить ссылку на сборку System.Xml.Linq.dll. Затем открываем пространство имён:

```cpp
using namespace System::Xml::Linq;
```

Тип `docPoint` меняем на `XDocument`;

Считывание xml выглядит очень похоже (добавьте проверку на существование файла):

```cpp
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    docPoint = XDocument::Load(XmlPoint);
    for each(XElement ^elem in docPoint->Root->Elements()) {
        comboBoxPoint->Items->Add(elem->Element("pr_name")->Value);         
    }
}
```

Все преимущества Linq to Xml проявлюятся при создании документа. Узел создаётся и добавляется в дерево одновременно. Код получается намного короче. (И назовите эту кнопку `buttonSave`).

```cpp
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {       

    XElement ^root = gcnew XElement(gcnew String("NewDataSet"));

    XDocument ^doc = gcnew XDocument(
        gcnew XDeclaration("1.0", nullptr, "yes"),
        root
    );

    for (int j = 0; j < listBoxViewSelectPoint->Items->Count; j++)
    {
        String ^ElementListBox = listBoxViewSelectPoint->Items[j]->ToString();
        for each(XElement ^elem in docPoint->Root->Elements())
        {
            if (ElementListBox == elem->Element("pr_name")->Value)
            {
                String ^PointAtribut1 = elem->Element("atribut1")->Value;
                String ^PointAtribut2 = elem->Element("atribut2")->Value;

                root->Add(
                    gcnew XElement(gcnew String("point"),
                        gcnew XElement(gcnew String("pr_name"), ElementListBox),
                        gcnew XElement(gcnew String("atribut1"), PointAtribut1),
                        gcnew XElement(gcnew String("atribut2"), PointAtribut2)
                ));
            }
        }
    }
    doc->Save(filename);
}
```

Более того, так как по сути узлы `point` копируются целиком из оригинального документа, то код можно ещё упростить:

```cpp
for each(XElement ^elem in docPoint->Root->Elements())
{
    if (ElementListBox == elem->Element("pr_name")->Value)
    {
        root->Add(gcnew XElement(elem));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! Но почему то при сборке ругается на Root в docPoint->Root->Elements()

Comment: @bastet - `docPoint` должен быть типа `XDocument`, не `XmlDocument`.